the dag is getting triggered immediately when toggle is ON
This is my dag:
dag_pr_api = DAG(
    dag_id='API-PERSONAL-COMPUTER',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='30 07 * * *',
    start_date=pendulum.yesterday('Europe/Berlin'),
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=['ssh']
)

when I enabling the dag in airflow UI, it is getting triggered immediately. I have gone through several articles but i didnt understood the issue with start_date
can someone help?
I tried catchup=False still issue didnt resolved

The first run of a DAG is always the start_date + schedule_interval. It doesn't happen on the actual start_date.
In your case, your start date start_date=pendulum.yesterday('Europe/Berlin') will be a date from yesterday, and as it satisfies the trigger condition start_date + schedule_interval, it triggers a DAG run.
It is always advisable to not keep the start_date parameter dynamic. Check: https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/dag-best-practices#use-dag-name-and-start-date-properly
To understand more about start_date, have a look here:
https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/scheduling-in-airflow#parameters
https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date
In your case, you can keep a static value of start_date, e.g. today's date datetime(current_year, current_month, current_day), if you want the DAG to trigger tomorrow, and so on.
